# Scala: Task not serializable when using closure

Tags: scala, apache-spark, runtime-error

So I am fairly new to Spark and Scala and from my understanding you should be able to pass a closure into a map function and have it modify the values however I am getting the `Task not serializable` error when attempting this.

My code is as follows:

```
// Spark Context
val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext
val random = scala.util.Random

// RDD Initialization
val array = Seq.fill(500)(random.nextInt(51))
val RDD = sc.parallelize(array)

// Spark Operations for Count, Sum, and Mean
var count = RDD.count()
var sum = RDD.reduce(_+_)
val mean = sum / count;

//Output Count, Sum, and Mean
println("Count: " + count)
println("Sum: " + sum)
println("Mean: " + mean)

val difference = (x:Int) => {x - mean}

var differences = RDD.map(difference)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining a function, try using a val fun

```
val difference = (x:Int) => {x-mean}
```

When you use `def` to define a function, Spark would try to serialize your object that has this function. This usually results into TaskNotSerializable as there might be something (val or var) in that Object which is not serializable.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix my error however if i replace mean with a constant int like 2 then it runs perfectly fine so it has something to do with my mean value which is of type long

Comment: oh okay, can you show where your mean value resides. if it is a basic datatype, it should not error out for serialization.

Comment: I do not think 'mean' is causing this problem to you. The object of which the above code is part of, does it have anything that is not serializable. If you could share your scala code in full that might give some hint

Comment: I tried putting your code in a scala file and passing it to spark2-shell and it worked fine without any errors. You might have something else in your application that is causing your trouble.